# Maui integrate Unity as a library?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, maui

Is it possible to integrate Unity as a Library into a Maui project like you can already do with Unity as a lib and native android and native ios or even flutter projects?

If so, how would that look like and how do you create a unity activity instance?
There literally no sources on that topic.

Comment: Unity use their own fork of mono so it should be able to run (some) .net standard code but .net standard cannot use it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I thought they had migrated their code to run on .Net Core, but I see that they have only done the first step, compatibility. So customers can run code developed for .Net Core. https://blog.unity.com/engine-platform/unity-and-net-whats-next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend asking this on a Unity forum. Plus make a "feature request" to Unity devs. Would need their expertise to get this to work well.

[OPINIONS FOLLOW]

At this time, I don't recommend trying to use Maui and Unity together.

**A cleaner solution** is to run **Unity on .Net 7**, once that works. Use **Unity's "UI Toolkit"** for your UI.

**This lets Microsoft do what they have done best, the low-level "plumbing", and uses a single vendor (Unity) for all the code that interacts with display (or VR headset) and with user.**

This will give you **Microsoft's advances** in cross-platform c# performance and language features, plus allow **Unity** to be your UI, as well as your 3D/VR/AR solution.

(I predict challenges in getting Maui + Unity to work smoothly together cross-platform. Avoid until proven otherwise.)

Caveat: I have not used Unity's UI Toolkit.